# Can anyone suggest me a DFT or FFT tool for image analysis?

Tags: image-processing, video-processing

I would like to compare two video files for the file which is having a better quality (Non blurry) by a c programm.A friend told me to learn about DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform) for image analysis and to use a FFT or DFT tool to learn the difference between blurred vs detailed (non-blurry) copies of same image.So can anyone help me with this ??

Comment: Convolution is taking FT of both data and operator, multiplying results element-wise, taking IFT of that. What kind of operator is that yours?

Comment: Hi @VC.One can you help me with this ??

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with SSIM or PSNR. Both can can be done in C and there are C++/C#/Cuda versions of these algorithms on the net.

Doug